# How to use different domains subdomains in WP multisite?

Tags: multisite, subdomains

In my multisite I would like to use these domains and domains, how do I set it up?

- site1.com
- sub1.site1.com
- site2.org
- sub2.site2.org

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The wordpress.org support article for multisite domain mapping should help you set up the custom domains, https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-multisite-domain-mapping/

Comment: So in the example of the image above I can just set "https://sub2.site2.org/" instead of "http://example.net/" ? Even though my main domain is site1.com?

Comment: According to the documentation and to my understanding, yes, that is how it should work.